# pyodbc error: Data source name not found (Win8)

Tags: python, driver, pyodbc

I am trying to connect using the pyodbc capability with the following connection string:
`DRIVER={SQL Native Client}`.

Getting the following error:

```
Error connecting to database: [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)
```

Main issue is that on my machine everything works like a charm, while execution on other machines return the error above.

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you copy the connection string you're using here?

Answer (score 0):

That is presumably because your connection string specifies some Windows datasource (a datasource is effectively an os-level alias) which exists on your machine, but does not exist on the other machines.  You probably need to define the datasource on the other machines.

As Flipper suggests, first check out your connection string to determine what the name of the datasource is.  Then check on your machine how that datasource is configured, then create and configure similar datasources on the other machines.

maybe check out the info and links on this ms dev-net page on datasources:

[ODBC Data Source Administrator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714024%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

All Windows installs include a copy of the older "SQL Server" ODBC driver

`Driver={SQL Server}`

so that should be available on any Windows machine for both 32-bit and 64-bit applications.

More recent versions of SQL Server have introduced their own client software to support their latest features. Drivers like

`Driver={SQL Native Client}` (9.0, for SQL Server 2005)
`Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0}` (for SQL Server 2008)
`Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}` (for SQL Server 2012/2014)

will only work if the machine has the required SQL Server client software installed. (It can be downloaded and installed separately for machines that don't run SQL Server itself, usually as part of a "SQL Server Feature Pack".)

So, if you really need the more advanced features of the later "Native Client" ODBC driver then you will have to ensure that it gets installed on the other machines. Otherwise, just stick with the older "SQL Server" driver.